# Check whether debug is enabled in a Pylons application

Tags: python, configuration, pylons

I'm working on a fairly simple Pylons 0.9.7 application. How do I tell, in code, whether or not debugging is enabled? That is, I'm interested in the value of the **debug** setting under **[app:main]** in my INI file. More generally, how do I access the other values from there in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# tmp.py
print __debug__


$ python tmp.py
True
$ python -O tmp.py
False
```

I'm not sure if this holds in Pylons, as I've never used that -- but in "normal" command line Python, debug is enabled if optimizations are *not* enabled.  The `-O` flag indicates to Python to turn on optimizations.

Actually, there's this snippet from [Pylons documentation](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.0/pylons-internal-architecture.html#the-pylons-middleware-stack):

```
    # Display error documents for 401, 403, 404 status codes (and
    # 500 when debug is disabled)
    if asbool(config['debug']):
        app = StatusCodeRedirect(app)
    else:
        app = StatusCodeRedirect(app, [400, 401, 403, 404, 500])
```

Looks like `config['debug']` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, config['debug'] has the value I want. I did look in the Pylons documentation, but looks like I missed it.